# How to run callback with jest --watch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

I started to learn ReactJS yesterday (to be used in my next product), I am willing to set up my dev environment but now I'm stuck with Jest...

Having a bluetooth lightbulb on my desk (already op with scripts etc..), I want to get a red light when my tests launched with `jest --watch` fail (see create-react-app from FB devs [here](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app))
The problem is, I don't know how to run a callback after the tests, it seems like no one ran into this issue on the interwebz, no solution found yet for me.

---

### Update:

I am currently using a log file to grep:

lamp.rb

```
def ci
  if File.readlines("path/jest.log").grep(/failed/).any?
    File.truncate('path/jest.log', 0)
    fail_jest # This method updates my lightbulb :) (red blink)
  end
rescue
  puts 'No jest log found :('
end
```

Launching my jest tests like this: `unbuffer npm run test |& tee tmp/jest.log`

---

I am still looking for a better solution !

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not specific to React or Jest. When your run jest tests, you are basically running a Node/npm command and when the tests fail the process exists with an unsuccessful exit code. This is the same mechanism used to make automated CI builds fail when tests don't pass. So I'd suggest you start your research from there and depending on your lightbulb's API, it should be straight forward to make it fire events whenever the process fails regardless of the reason.

Comment: Of course, but the way it is started (--watch), I won't have any exit code